# Best practice to store the json data into database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I am working on storing a json data into data base and me and my colleagues
where having discussion which will be the best way to store.

As I know that PostgresSql provide you Jsonb datatype to store the json in the column so to handle that I have written some custom dialect which store json data in jsonb column

But my colleagues were not satisfied with that approach his approach was to convert the object into json by using the object mapper and store that json in from of string where column type will be a character varying.

So can anyone tell me which will be best way to do it? Or is there any best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way with jsonb and dialect is better:

1) You can search by separate json field or complex internal json structure.

2) You are able to partially update the json, no need to rewrite whole json

3) You have ability to use postgress json functions on views

4) You can create an index on specific json field

Drawbacks:

1) You have to create dialect and support this code.

2) Jsonb may take more disk space